# how run dependent cmd commands in java

Tags: java, cmd

Hi I need execute several cmd commands with depend on each other in java:

```
cd  "C:\Program Files (x86)\puTTY"
pscp   -pw pwd F:\Test\file_to_send.txt login@my_ip:/home/bin
```

I tried such ways:

1)

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start F:\\Test\\move_to_linux.bat");` and set in bat file:

```
cd  "C:\Program Files (x86)\puTTY"
pscp   -pw pwd F:\Test\file_to_send.txt login@my_ip:/home/bin
```

2)

```
try {
        String[] command = new String[3];
        command[0] = "cmd";
        command[1] = "/c";
        command[2] = "cd \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\puTTY\" && pscp   -pw pwd F:\\Test\\file_to_send.txt login@my_ip:/home/bin";

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String Error;
        while ((Error = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(Error);
        }
        while ((Error = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(Error);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In 1) cmd opens in  F:\Test folder and commands runs separatelly each from F:\Test.
In 2) 'pscp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/) is a good example of how to run shell commands. You don't need to open putty to run system commands.

You can use the native java libraries to execute shell commands, just be aware that the commands are OS-specific. I've done this before for a project where we had to simulate a shell in java, it's pretty easy once you know what you're doing.

I wold recommend modularizing your code a little. For example

1. Read user input
2. Parse user input
3. Return error or execute command